# How to search contents of multiple pdf files and return the pdf's file name?

Tags: linux, pdf, full-text-search, grep, debian

I did a search here and found this one:

```
find /path -name '*.pdf' -exec pdftotext {} - \; | grep "your query"
```

However, it returns the text block inside the pdf files that have "your query". Have a method to return the file name instead?

Answer (score 2):

As suggsted by Neil: you can use the `-l` option. If you need the count of matches too,
you can try this:

```
find /path -name '*.pdf' -exec pdftotext {} - \; | grep -H -c "your query"
```

The `-H` option prints the filename and the `-c` option prints the count. You can strip the count out later of course.

Answer (score 2):

This lists all the files whose text conversion matches your query:

```
find /path -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c "pdftotext {} - | grep --label {} -l 'your query'" \;
```